# Devexpress LookupEdit issue ,change it manually

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit, gridlookupedit

I have 2 lookupedit witch are exactly the same in everything but the value member 
one of them is binded to an int32 column and it can be changed by changing the editvalue in code

The other one is binded to int64 and it can't be changed manually

Why Is That And how can i fix it

Comment: This is not a problem with the control; ie this should work.  You will need to post a little bit of code that shows how to reproduce this problem and we can assist.

Comment: The problematic one has ValueMember set to a non-existent property.

Comment: no it's valueMember is binded to int64